# CodeIgniter input Library is Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

When I use `$this->input->post('something');` in CodeIgniter while making Shopping cart, my data is not inserting in to the cart/session. I have autoload session, cart, database, input as well. But no receiving any data.

When I `print_r($data)` I got all data but when I put it in `$this->cart->insert($data)` no data comes in it.

How can I solve this problem. My code is here below:

View

```
<form action="<?=  site_url()?>product/add" method="post">
<input type="number" name="qty" min="1" max="99" required="required" />
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $value->proid;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?= $value->price;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?= $value->title;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to Cart" />
</form>
```

Controller

```
class Product extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){
        $data['products'] = $this->product_model->get_all();
        $this->load->view('products',$data);
    }

    public function add(){

        $id = $this->input->post('id',TRUE);
        $qty = $this->input->post('qty',TRUE);
        $price = $this->input->post('price',TRUE);
        $name = $this->input->post('name',TRUE);

        $data = array(
            'id'      => $id,
            'qty'     => $qty,
            'price'   => $price,
            'name'    => $name
        );

        $this->cart->insert($data);

        redirect('product','refresh');

    }

}
```

Comment: `print_r($product)` and post answer

Comment: its showing results if i add product detail manually, but if i try to get it from input->post it shows nothing... it returns me an empty array...

Comment: what this shows ?? `$this->input->post('id');`

Comment: i have made some hidden fields inside the form. and id is in one of them.let me show you my view:

Comment: delete above comment and add in your question

Comment: i am getting values from that hidden fields. when i run script and print_r() it shows me all values accordingly.but when i insert them in cart it returns empty array.

Comment: is this getiing any answer?? `$this->input->post('id');` and add you **Model code** in your question

Comment: yes i get product id from it when i print_r().... but when i insert in it array() of cart it returns empty array().

Comment: change this `redirect('product','refresh');` to this `redirect('product');`

Comment: i have did this.... but nothing happen.... still not receiving data....

Comment: not receiving means??

Comment: i have even made a ci_session table in mysql to store the session data... but doesn't help me...

Comment: Means that.... I can't see any product data in my cart.... after updating ('product')

Comment: no this works well. Check [this](http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-shopping-cart/)

Comment: yes I know that site... its good... but my cart is not working.. I get stuck in it since morning.... i completely lost in it. its not working

Comment: Note:  I would not use site url in form action use base_url `action="<?php echo base_url('product/add');?>"` Make your you have set your base_url correct in config though do not leave it empty

Comment: what function is this calling? `$this->cart->insert($data);`